# Build angular project using AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

We have an Angular project and we are trying to use AWS CodePipeline to deploy the project.

We have pushed our project to a CodeCommit repository.

Now we are facing challenge to generate the build using AWS CodeBuild. In CodeBuild the build definition is

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install && ng build-prod
```

We get an error `ng: not found`

We also tried the following build definition:

```
phases:
      build:
        commands:
          - npm install && run build-prod
```

Error we get is `run: not found`

Also we are not sure about what we have to enter in "Output files" field.

Please Help..!!

Answer (score 26):

The Node.js container from CodeBuild doesn't have the angular-cli installed. Just Node.js and npm. You must install angular-cli before build your project. Above there are a buildspec.yml example for a angular project to be deployed in S3 bucket:

```
version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        CACHE_CONTROL: "86400"
        S3_BUCKET: {-INSERT BUCKET NAME FOR STATIC WEBSITE HERE-}
        BUILD_FOLDER: {-INSERT THE NAME OF THE BUILD FOLDER HERE-}
        BUILD_ENV: "prod"
phases:
    install:
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --${BUILD_ENV}
    post_build:
         commands:
            - aws s3 cp ${BUILD_FOLDER} s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive --acl public-read --cache-control "max-age=${CACHE_CONTROL}"
            - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
    files:
        - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'dist*'
    discard-paths: yes
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using a similar buildspec file and everything work until the post_build phase when the copy is suppose to start. I get this error for all my file `delete failed: s3://trips9ja-admin/index.html An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied`

Comment: Check your S3 bucket permissions.... As my knowledge the DeleteObject operation would not be needed... Probably you gonna need to deep dive to understand what he is trying to delete...

Comment: I actually want the previous app files in the s3 bucket deleted then copy the newer version into the bucket from the dist folder. Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630610/automating-angular-7-app-deployment-with-aws-s3-and-codepipeline

Comment: So.. Just remove everything after the first three dots in my response... or in other words "Check your S3 bucket permissions...." They are just telling that you do not have rights to delete the object... also give an up in my response to help me a little bit.. ;-)

Comment: @GustavoTavares how and where to get `{-INSERT THE NAME OF THE BUILD FOLDER HERE-}`

Comment: It is the folder name of where your transpiler code is. Normally is dist or build.... you need to check inside your webpack script...

Comment: "discard-paths: yes" is not what you usually want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something wrong with your npm install. Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli

The output files should be, the files you want to upload to your artifact s3 bucket, like: appspec.yml, target/my-app.jar.
You can check the Artifact section in our doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html?icmpid=docs_acb_console#create-project-console
Thanks
Xin

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you're using angular-cli as a devDependencies. With devDependencies, you have to use node to run it or you have to put write the script to run it inside package.json file. For examples:

```
node ./node_module/@angular/cli/bin/ng <rest of the params>
```

or inside package.json file, you have to add a command definition in scripts property and run with npm: `npm run <command-name>`

```
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    ...
    "ng": "ng"
  }
  ...
}
```

In your question, you already use options 2. But looks like you're missing npm at the beginning of the command. It should be like this:

```
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - npm install && npm run build-prod
```

Hope it helps!